# Is there simple way to extend simply typed lambda calculus with monad types?

Tags: haskell, programming-languages, monads, lambda-calculus, typed-lambda-calculus

How can one extend simply typed lambda calculus to have a type system that supports something like a monad type? Basically, I presently have a nice understanding of simply typed lambda calculus, and I'd like to understand the "minimal requirements" to add monads to that foundation. By "adding monads" I mean anything that would result in a language with an operational semantics and type assignment that allows one to recognize the "usefulness" of monads for programs, to some extent. For example, Haskell supports monads in reasonable sense even though it doesn't require the programmer to fully prove that their "monad" instance actually abides by the monad laws.

I'm hoping to understand some minimal way of extending STLC with monads in order to learn more about monads in relation to programming language theory. Personally, I find it easier to learn these things in a more stripped down/essential setting (as opposed to just using them in practice in a language like haskell). For this reason, I can't give any more of a precise description of what I'm looking for, than what I wrote above.

Edit, with regard to @Ben's comment: could you not have some kind of setup where you have a signature of "atomic" monads *M*, and then your simple types *T* are now:

*T* = *σ* | *T*<sub>1</sub> → *T*<sub>2</sub> | *m* *T*

where *σ* is an atomic type from the signature of atomic types, and *m* is an element of *M*.

And then maybe you also add constant terms to the lambda calculus terms:

*t* = *x* | *t*<sub>1</sub> *t*<sub>2</sub> | λ *x*.*t* | return *t* | *t*<sub>1</sub> >>= *t*<sub>2</sub>$

I'm not sure if any of this would work, but it seems like something like this would be possible.

Comment: Voting to close due to seeking recommendations.

Comment: I think you'd need higher kinded types, polymorphism, the definition of new types inside the language, and some concept along the lines of interfaces or type classes, before you even have the language features necessary to talk about monads. I'd be interested in seeing how minimalist you can go (and how wrong I am), but I don't think you'll end up with something very close to **simply** typed lambda calculus.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard: sorry I wasn't aware of that norm. I can re-phrase the question as a direct technical question.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I don't think it's the *kind* of "seeking recommendations" question I would call off-topic; it's not the classic "what's the best library/book/tutorial for X" that leads to opinion based answers which will be out of date in a year. Whether this kind of calculus system exists as a thing people have considered is not opinion based. It might be a better fit at cstheory.stackexchange.com though?

Comment: I re-phrased to directly ask my true question. Now someone can directly answer, or just refer me to a source.

Comment: @Ben: I added an edit to describe what I was thinking about. I could spend days trying to flesh out this setup, but if there is an expert out there that has worked all of this out already it would be great to know about it.

Comment: @ttbo no worries, I retracted and upvoted.

Comment: @ttbo Yeah, I get that. I'm not enough of an expert to say (or I'd write an answer). I can see how that sort of approach might work (although I think you'll need to specify which M you're talking about in the `return` and `>>=` calls), with some of the polymorphism, higher-kinded types etc embedded in your typing rules for a collection of built in monads instead of generally supported in the language. Where I suspect this will miss the mark is the ability to write *generic* monad code, which is a key part of their actual benefit in languages that support monads. (1/2)

Comment: @ttbo "Being a monad" adds nothing to the capabilities of any one monadic type, considered alone. e.g. We can do all the same things with `\x -> [x]`, `concat` and `map` that we can do with the specific `return` and `>>=` for lists. What the monad abstraction gets us is the ability to use it **as an abstraction**. There are lots of cases where someone's written code that works for any monad, and somebody else plugs in a novel monad they didn't think of and gets something useful. So to help you understand how monads affect a language, you really need a system that can model that.

Comment: @ttbo Maybe if you also had the ability to take a parameter `m : M`, which isn't an actual *value* but can be "passed to" `return` and `>>=` (or to other things with a parameter of type `M`) to specify which monad you're talking about. (In Haskell type inference usually fills in this parameter for you, but it really exists in the underlying system). 'll stop brainstorming in the comments now though, and leave it to someone who knows what they're talking about to say that t works or doesn't.

Comment: @ttbo Oh, we don't have latex here on stackoverflow, so you'll want to use ASCII standins for the symbols or render to an image and include that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is already addressed by Eugenio Moggi's 1991 seminal paper, "Notions of computation and monads." Here's a link: [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~crary/819-f09/Moggi91.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ecrary/819-f09/Moggi91.pdf)

In particular, Section 2.3 explains how to interpret a simple programming language based on lambda-calculus in a monadic framework. Note that it doesn't matter if you add `return`, `>>=` etc; it's the semantics you give to your expressions and statements that are monadic. Haskell makes this explicit by separating the "pure" parts from the "monadic" parts in a syntactically nice way, whereas ML/Scheme etc. make it "convoluted" by keeping both look the same in the type system, but allow interpretations over suitable monads.